# If Statements counterpart in assembly (NASM)?

Tags: assembly, if-statement, nasm

I am looking for a command works similar to an if statement in Java, C, etc. for assembly language and I am using the NASM.

If want it to branch the program if the input nummer is smaller than zero, greater than one-hundred or is between zero and one-hundred. And I have not got a clue how to realize this checkback.

Comment: What have you tried?  What you're describing is fairly simple.  Potentially useful (though by no means a replacement for a good book): http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Branches

Comment: that links looks good, I will take a look, thanks mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Corbin, 
I solved it with this

```
;check if n is between 0 and 100
cmp     eax, [e2]
jg      end_if1
jmp         next

next:
cmp     eax,[e1]
jl      end_if2
jmp         math
```

Your link helped me a lot :) Have a nice day Sir!

Comment: `jmp next` is a no-op, so this either buggy or over-complicated.  Hard to tell which because the target labels like `end_if1` aren't present.  Also, to check for eax >=0 and <= 100, you can `cmp eax, 100` / `ja out_of_range` / else fall through, because negative 2's complement numbers are large unsigned numbers.